# How to update a existing entity in datastore using golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to find an effective example in how to perform updates on appengine datastore with Go. All the examples I've found on the web are very vague and mostly explains concepts and not the "real life". The appengine documentation for go says:

..."Updating an existing entity is a matter of performing another Put() using the same key."

Please can anyone help me i was unable to solve these.

Comment: Are you taking about AppEngine Standard or AppEngine Flexible?

Comment: i am using AppEngine Standard                                                                                       and package is ("google.golang.org/appengine/datastore")